# How to achieve a read only connection using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to achieve a read-only connection to the secondary nodes of the MongoDB.
I have a primary node and two secondary nodes. I want a read-only connection to secondary nodes.

I tried `MongoReplicaSetClient` but did not get what I wanted.
Is it possible to have a read-only connection to primary node?

Comment: read-only to primary or secondary?

Comment: @Astro read only to secondary

Comment: secondaries are read only by default..however, you can specify the read preference to read from secondaries. By default it reads from primary.

Comment: @Astro  Can I specify so that it connects only to secondary and never to primary?

Comment: yes using readPreference=secondary in connection string

Comment: If a write attempt is made will it fail or will it be written with primary ?

Comment: will be written to primary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138290/discussion-between-dev-avatar-and-astro).

Comment: I achieved this by creating a read-only account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to specify a [Read Preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) on your queries. A read preference of [Secondary Preferred](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#read-preference-modes) will send queries to a Secondary node but will fall back to the Primary in the event that a Secondary is not available.

The read preference in pymongo is configured in the MongoClient:

```
>>> client = MongoClient(
...     'localhost:27017',
...     replicaSet='foo',
...     readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
>>> client.read_preference
SecondaryPreferred(tag_sets=None)
```

More information (and source of above) can be found [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#read-preference-modes)

Comment: It may be safer from a read-only point of view to specify `readPreference='secondary'`.

Comment: In my practise, readPreference only affect where you read, it does not forbidden you from writing to primary, so, I can still update my collection in mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Secondaries are read-only by default. However, you can specify the read preference to read from secondaries. By default, it reads from the primary.

This can be achieved using readPreference=secondary in connection string