# Read-only mode for a pymongo.MongoClient connection to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

For [a project](https://github.com/greenelab/crossref/tree/619507cd422b29d73bb1621c1cab3745a509c2b8#mongodb), I'm currently running a local MongoDB instance without authentication.

I connect to the database in python using pymongo. For most use cases, I'll only want to run read queries. I'd like to specify a read-only `pymongo.MongoClient` connection, so I can avoid accidental write operations, which could mess up the database.

---

There is an existing [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849056/how-to-achieve-a-read-only-connection-using-pymongo) that is in the context of replicas. In my case, there is a single node running in Docker. I also looked through the [read preference docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to prevent accidentally modifying your MongoDB data is by enabling authentication. PyMongo and other drivers do not have a feature that can accomplish this goal.

Comment: Thanks @a-jesse-jiryu-davis, that answers my question! I noticed that the [mongo repositories](https://github.com/mongodb) on GitHub don't allow Issues, otherwise I'd open a feature request.

Comment: Go to jira.mongodb.org to open a feature request. But since authentication is an existing, robust feature that allows you to accomplish precisely what you're asking for, I don't think your feature request will be implemented. =)